# How to address the current cell in conditional format custom formula?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I need to write a conditional format rule with a custom formula, that should trigger when the certain cell's (the cell in the 3rd row of the column of the current cell) value is `"TODAY()"`, and the current cell is `empty`. I know how to check the other cell, but is there a way to check the current cell's value in the same rule?

As you can see on this image, one column has a different color because the 3rd row of the column of the current cell contains the current date. And only empty cells are colored.
[image]

Here is my rule:

`=and($3:$3=TODAY(), ????)`

It should apply to all cells in a range `A4:M10`

I need it to be the one rule, not combination of multiple rules. I need to put something to the place of `????`

In other words, I need to place the value described as "Cell is empty" in the custom formula as it's part.

Here is an example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vpNrX2aUg8vY5WGDDuBnLfPuL-UyrjFvzjdATS73aq8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the 2 tables in your example look exactly alike on my google spreadsheet android app, not sure what is the problem

Comment: I have a question not about Android, sorry. The difference is in the color of one column

Comment: ah. i can see it now even in adroid. at the time the question was about non-empty cells which were all the same... will have a look later

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The current cell is addressed by the **first cell of a range in the conditional formatting**. In your example, the range is `A4:M10` and therefore you can use `A4` as "current cell".

- Check for empty content:

  ```
  =A4=""
  ```

---

Relative vs absolute references in conditional formatting work [just like copying a formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21).

- Check that the cell in 2nd row of current column row is today:

  ```
  =A$2=TODAY()
  ```
- Combine using `AND` operator:

  ```
  =AND(A$2=TODAY(), A4="")
  ```

I have updated a copy of your example spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MY9Jn2xpoVoBeJOa2rkZgv5HXKyQ9I8SM3kiUPR9oXU/edit#gid=0

Comment: Your google sheet has no read access to the conditional formatting. So I cannot see the formulas :(

Comment: @moobi no idea how to add permission for people to view it directly, please download the file and/or copy it to your own google drive

Answer (score 64):

If I want to check if current cell is empty this is working for me:

```
=ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))
```

The cell at the previous row in the column will be

`=ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW() - 1,COLUMN())))` etc.

Comment: You will also need to enable "Iterative Calculations". 
Please go to File > Spreadsheet Settings 

and enable on **Calculation** tab **Iterative Calculation**

Comment: I used `;` instead of `,` to separate parameters

Answer (score 46):

This is the shortest possible way I've found to reference the current cell in conditional formatting spanning a range:

`INDIRECT("RC",FALSE)`.

Documentation is [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en).

Comment: This looks like the most elegant way to use "this cell" in conditional formatting, I like it.  However I cannot find anywhere that says using "RC" without any numbers will do what you predict.  *It works* but I don't see it in documentation, including the document to which you link here!  What made you even attempt it?

Comment: I can't remember anymore and R1C1 is ancient in origin so I haven't found any formal specification. I probably found it while searching the web, here's an example of an article that mentions the "RC" method: https://powerspreadsheets.com/r1c1-formular1c1-vba/ ['…Finally, if you're referring to the cell itself (creating a circular reference), the first portion of the cell reference is simply “R”…']

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I found the answer myself. The correct complete formula is:

```
=and($2:$2=TODAY(),INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)="")
```

This rule:

```
INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)=""
```

checks if the current cell is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try apply to range:

```
A3:M10
```

Custom formula is:

```
=$2:$2=TODAY()
```

Comment: No, 3:3 will check only one cell, I need to check all cells in a range

Answer (score 0):

In your custom function rewrite the original conditional formatting range. The spreadsheet application will then take the current cell. As a result, your formula will be something like this

```
=function(A4:M10)
```

Apply transformations as necessary to make the result truthy/falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my two cents;

Another way to check that the current cell is different from the cell in the previous column;

```
=INDIRECT("RC",FALSE) <> OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC", FALSE), 0, -1)
```